# Viewing a file stored in Varbinary(MAX) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ms-access, file-io

Let's say I inserted a file into a `varbinary(max)` field like so:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
      FileName nvarchar(60),
      FileType nvarchar(60), 
      Document varbinary(max)
)
GO

INSERT INTO myTable(FileName, FileType, field_varbinary)
    SELECT 
        'Text1.txt' AS FileName, 
        '.txt' AS FileType,
        * 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document
GO
```

Of course my file now looks like this:

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800....
```

Is there a simple and elegant way to retrieve this file?

My preference is to open it right away in a temp folder rather than saving and then viewing and deleting. In MS Access, this is as simple as using an Attachment field and double clicking to upload/download.

Comment: SQL Server is not a client application. You need an application that can open your file. Just querying it in sql server is not going to work.

Comment: yeah i know... can you offer a solution

Comment: How could I do that? I don't know what application you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working with C# and ASP.NET, and I ended up doing this using a Generic Handler, later linking to it elsewhere in my website project:

```
public class ImageProvider : IHttpHandler {
    public string connString = "...";

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        string sqlSelectQuery = "select img from table"
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, conn);

        byte[] img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(img);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no built-in functionality in SSMS for this task I usually write a simple LINQPad script that extracts my varbinary column and writes it to the file system.

Something like this:

```cs
var results = from p in myTable 
                       where p.ID == ... //your condition here
                       select p;

foreach (var item in results)
{ 
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\" + item.FileName + item.FileType , item.Document.ToArray());
}
```